# Adding information to the database

Tags: android

If I created a database in MainActivity:

```
RankingDBHelper rankingDBHelper = new RankingDBHelper(this);
mDatabase = rankingDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

And then in DialogFragment I want to add data to the database, how should I do it?

Should i do the same as in MainActivity?

```
RankingDBHelper rankingDBHelper = new RankingDBHelper(this);
mDatabase = rankingDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
contentValues.put(COLUMN_SCORE, score);
contentValues.put(COLUMN_LEVEL, level);
contentValues.put(COLUMN_MULTIPLIER, multiplier);
```

Or should the mDatabase reference variable be static?

```
static mDatabase;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use the SingleTon design pattern to get the reference of the SQLiteDatabase Object. For reference see this [post](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html).

Comment: I understand, but I have to use the getWritableDatabase method to create a database. So in that case would it be good to use the getWritableDatabase method in MainActivity and getInstance () in DialogFragment?